# Phonegap - iOS screen size

Tags: cordova

Busy working on a cross platform Phonegap application, building through build.phonegap.com. I have however noticed that when testing it on Iphone 5, it displays as if an Iphone 4 - not the full screen.
Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by "not the full screen", is it due to the status bar.

Comment: Do you mean the total height of the application or are you talking about the status bar on the top?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was resolved by adding the appropriate splash screen for the iphone 5.

Comment: It is worth noting that the appropriate splash screen image is included in a default phonegap application (PhoneGap 3.3), it is just not referenced in the config.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know what cordova version you are using?

Please check iOS Configuration from below link :
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/guide_platforms_ios_config.md.html

In this link you see the property 
a) GapBetweenPages
b) PageLength